# iOS alert banner/label?

Tags: ios, notifications

I apologize if this question is very basic.  I have been googling around but can't seem to find the api/reference for a drop down alert banner/label (I do not know the proper term for **this**), therefore I am posting here.

This: The label/banner which has "Please enter valid email address" in it.

[image]

So here a my questions:

- What is the proper term for this (alert banner? notification? label?)
- I am trying accomplish similar functionality to what is shown in the image, so basically if any field is invalid, the "label/banner" expands from underneath the navigation bar with the message in it:
  If this is just a UILabel, what is the simplest way of adding the expand animation?
  If it is something built in, since I have seen bunch of apps do it for alerting, please let me know what its called.

Comment: Your probably looking for this... https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ajnotificationview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alert), I'm sure you will be able to find something to suite your needs.

The basic idea is that its simply a UIView that you animate down from the top of the screen (at the very basic). You can get a lot fancier by adding gradients, touch recognizers to dismiss it, etc. But pretty much to get the base line functionality you would just do something like this:

```
//Create a view to hold the label and add images or whatever, place it off screen at -100
UIView *alertview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 100)];

//Create a label to display the message and add it to the alertView
UILabel *theMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(alertview.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(alertview.bounds))];
theMessage.text = @"I'm an alert";
[alertview addSubview:theMessage];

//Add the alertView to your view
[self.view addSubview:alertview];

//Create the ending frame or where you want it to end up on screen, in this case 0 y origin
CGRect newFrm = alertview.frame;
newFrm.origin.y = 0;

//Animate it in
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    alertview.frame = newFrm;
}];
```

Comment: This is just a side questions, since I have never programmatically created views before.  If I am using ARC, will this view get tracked as soon as it is added to the parent view or do I need to explicitly release it some where? (I am messing with gradient and color so I have those resources also that should be released?)

Comment: You don't need to release it if your using ARC and it will be tracked as soon as its added to the parent view.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my project - it might be just the thing you're looking for.

https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it. I created a very basic one that does the job for my project.

Answer (score 0):

For easier control over animating the alert, you can embed your custom view in a UIStackView and simply show/hide it in an animation block. That way will significantly reduce the amount of code needed to animate the visibility of the alert.